# jQuery Animate not working on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a little issue here with Google Chrome. My code works pretty well with Safari, which makes me think it should work fine with Google Chrome. But Chrome doesn't animate as expected. What could be wrong?

```
$(function() {
    var sourceFoto = $(".empreendimento .main-photo img").attr("src");
    var alturaFoto;
    var larguraFoto;
    var limiteX;
    var limiteY;
    $(document).load(sourceFoto, function() {

        alturaFoto = $(".empreendimento .main-photo img").height();
        larguraFoto = $(".empreendimento .main-photo img").width();

        limiteY = Math.round(alturaFoto - 420);
        limiteX = Math.round(larguraFoto - 580);

        $(".empreendimento .main-photo img").animate({
            marginLeft: "-" + limiteX
        }, 5000, 'jswing').animate({
            marginTop: "-" + limiteY
        }, 5000, 'jswing').animate({
            marginLeft: "0px"
        }, 5000, 'jswing').animate({
            marginTop: "0px"
        }, 5000, 'jswing');

    });
});​
```

**Edit**

I've found the answer. Just loaded the image with `onLoad` method and worked pretty well.

```
image = new Image();

image.onload = function() {

    alturaFoto = $(".empreendimento .main-photo img").height();
    larguraFoto = $(".empreendimento .main-photo img").width();

    limiteY = Math.round(alturaFoto - 420);
    limiteX = Math.round(larguraFoto - 580);

    $(".empreendimento .main-photo img").animate({
        marginLeft: "-" + limiteX
    }, 5000).animate({
        marginTop: "-" + limiteY
    }, 5000).animate({
        marginLeft: "0px"
    }, 5000).animate({
        marginTop: "0px"
    }, 5000);

}

image.src = sourceFoto;​
```

Comment: Did you check that the values you pass into the animate method are the same in both browsers? If so, maybe it's a jQuery bug. If not, fix that issue.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your console? (Hit F12 in the browser and then browse to the page. Look in the bottom right corner and see if there are errors. If there are, click the notification and see what it says.)

Comment: What is supposed to be going on here?  That call to `.load()` has two parameters, which means that you're trying to load from that URL and overwrite the entire document. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: What is _"doesn't animate as expected"_ supposed to mean?

Answer (score 0):

Your `$(document).load(sourceFoto, function(){})` is the culprit. Your `sourceFoto` contains a URL, which is a string, which then triggers the jQuery [Ajax load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method. This load will either pass or fail, and trigger the callback.

The jQuery [load() event](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) suggests using a object to pass in event data rather than a string.

As to the mystery of why it didn't execute on Chrome, may I venture the possibility that you have this code in the `<head>` element? If you have it there, the value of the `sourceFoto` variable will be `undefined`. With the first argument to `load()` as `undefined`, the [load() event](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) will be trigged, binding the event handler (your animate function) to the page's load event.

However, this is is not the same as the [ready() event](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) that triggers *when the DOM is loaded*. I believe this is the function that you want. The [load() event](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) instead is used on:

> "...any element associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the window object."

Comment: All too correct, try looking at JSON style as that is really how jQuery like to pass the data, like: `{ key: 'value' }`, and as far as safari goes, i dont get it either, but safari and IE both stand out as crazy weird browsers with odd ideas of js interpertation. chorome and ff usually the best for pagges with js, in my opinion

Comment: @SpYk3HH, your comments make no sense... Chrome and Safari are both Webkit which means they both use the same JavaScriptCore.

Comment: @Sparky672 Webkit is the layout engine for both of them. Chrome and Safari have different JavaScript engines. ;)

Comment: I agree with you, but im already using the ready() method as you can see in the updated code above. The fact is im going this way because i need to js calculate the width and height of the image, which doesnt happens all the times if i take off the load method.

Comment: @Sparky672 lol, it would seem that way, but try setting up a json object with properties like `class` and watch safari go "nu uh!". I learned this the hard way as i coded a page once all in chrome and worked fine, but when i tested it in safari, half of it was broken due to custom json objects or whatever you wanna call em (i'm no grad student so the vocab is not my strong suite, simple been programming since i was 9 , mostly for fun till recent years made it a career, so i  might be using the vocb a bit wrong, but my point is still the same)

Comment: @LucasVeiga Have you tried binding the handler to the image's `load()` event? Because if `sourceFoto`'s value is no longer `undefined`, then your animation is triggering on Safari because of the Ajax load() method.

Also, note that the load event for images is unreliable. You can read about this on the [load() event](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)'s page.

Comment: Quote @JoshHah: _"Webkit is the layout engine for both of them. Chrome and Safari have different JavaScript engines."_  Then why does [Webkit have a built-in JavaScript engine](http://www.webkit.org/projects/javascript/index.html) if Chrome and Safari doesn't use it?

Comment: @Sparky672 Yes it does have JSCore in it, but Chrome does not utilize this. You can read about it here: http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/JavaScriptCore